Timeout and errors "This publisher only supports one subscriber" with Akka Stream
We sometimes face weird timeout errors in client code using Akka Stream which also manifests itself with some kind of bottlenecks/deadlocks and seeing calls fails from the client point-of-view even though everything indicates that server side of things works fine.
These errors are of 3 types:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: This publisher only supports one subscriber
java.io.IOException: Timeout after 60 seconds waiting for Initialized message from stage
java.io.IOException: Timeout on waiting for new data

See the corresponding stacktraces:
java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This publisher only supports one subscriber
    at akka.stream.impl.io.InputStreamAdapter.$anonfun$read$5(InputStreamSinkStage.scala:170)
    at apply @ com.mycompany.utils.Retry.$anonfun$run$2(Retry.scala:29)
    at fromFuture @ com.mycompany.utils.Retry.$anonfun$run$2(Retry.scala:29)
    at flatMap @ retry.package$RetryingOnSomeErrorsPartiallyApplied.$anonfun$apply$3(package.scala:101)
    at tailRecM @ retry.package$RetryingOnSomeErrorsPartiallyApplied.apply(package.scala:100)
    at *> @ retry.package$.$anonfun$retryingOnSomeErrorsImpl$3(package.scala:79)
    at map @ retry.package$.$anonfun$retryingOnSomeErrorsImpl$3(package.scala:76)
    at apply @ com.mycompany.utils.Retry.logError(Retry.scala:51)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This publisher only supports one subscriber
    at play.shaded.ahc.com.typesafe.netty.HandlerPublisher.subscribe(HandlerPublisher.java:167)
    at play.api.libs.ws.ahc.StandaloneAhcWSClient$$anon$2.subscribe(StandaloneAhcWSClient.scala:120)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$BatchingActorInputBoundary.preStart(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:148)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.init(GraphInterpreter.scala:306)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.init(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:619)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.tryInit(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:727)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.preStart(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:776)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundPreStart(Actor.scala:548)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundPreStart$(Actor.scala:548)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundPreStart(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:716)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:644)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:514)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:536)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:295)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:230)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)

java.io.IOException: Timeout after 60 seconds waiting for Initialized message from stage
    at akka.stream.impl.io.InputStreamAdapter.waitIfNotInitialized(InputStreamSinkStage.scala:224)
    at akka.stream.impl.io.InputStreamAdapter.executeIfNotClosed(InputStreamSinkStage.scala:130)
    at akka.stream.impl.io.InputStreamAdapter.read(InputStreamSinkStage.scala:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.ensureLoaded(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:539)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.detectEncoding(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:133)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.constructParser(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:256)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory._createParser(JsonFactory.java:1655)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:1083)
    at play.api.libs.json.jackson.JacksonJson$.parseJsValue(JacksonJson.scala:285)
    at play.api.libs.json.StaticBinding$.parseJsValue(StaticBinding.scala:21)
    at play.api.libs.json.Json$.parse(Json.scala:175)

java.io.IOException: Timeout on waiting for new data
    at akka.stream.impl.io.InputStreamAdapter.$anonfun$read$5(InputStreamSinkStage.scala:171)
    at apply @ com.mycompany.utils.Retry.$anonfun$run$2(Retry.scala:29)
    at fromFuture @ com.mycompany.utils.Retry.$anonfun$run$2(Retry.scala:29)
    at flatMap @ retry.package$RetryingOnSomeErrorsPartiallyApplied.$anonfun$apply$3(package.scala:101)
    at tailRecM @ retry.package$RetryingOnSomeErrorsPartiallyApplied.apply(package.scala:100)
    at *> @ retry.package$.$anonfun$retryingOnSomeErrorsImpl$3(package.scala:79)
    at map @ retry.package$.$anonfun$retryingOnSomeErrorsImpl$3(package.scala:76)
    at apply @ com.mycompany.utils.Retry.logError(Retry.scala:51)


After troubleshooting, we never fully understood the issue but it seems related to the usage of InputStream in combination with Akka Stream.
We removed usages of InputStreams and didn't face any issue anymore. (In our case, the InputStream was not useful and we could work without it.)
For instance, we changed from:
private def inputStreamSink(readTimeout: FiniteDuration): Sink[ByteString, InputStream] =
  StreamConverters.asInputStream(readTimeout)

To:
private def stringSink(charset: Charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Sink[ByteString, Future[String]] = {
  // Note: not using ByteStringBuilder because the zero element of a fold should be immutable in order to avoid weird issues
  // (A Sink must be a reusable piece)   
  Sink
    .fold[ByteString, ByteString](ByteString.empty) { case (acc, bs) => acc ++ bs }
    .mapMaterializedValue {
      _.map(_.decodeString(charset))
    }
}


As per Akka Stream documentation:

Warning
Be aware that asInputStream and asOutputStream materialize InputStream and OutputStream respectively as blocking API implementation. They will block the thread until data will be available from upstream. Because of blocking nature these objects cannot be used in mapMaterializeValue section as it causes deadlock of the stream materialization process. For example, following snippet will fall with timeout exception:
...
.toMat(StreamConverters.asInputStream().mapMaterializedValue { inputStream =>
       inputStream.read()  // this could block forever
       ...
}).run()


Possibly related issues:

https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/23570
https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/19392

